# Why aren't my AJAX requests going through?

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, post, flask

[This](https://github.com/joshua-yan/hackpsu-progress) is my github repository for [this](https://cb37048f.ngrok.io) live demo I have going on at the moment.

//index.js is where the POST request is being sent from

```
class Index extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
    };

    handleClickLoading = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            loading: true,
        }));
        var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
            async: true,
            data: { mydata: [Cookies.get('links'), Cookies.get('numSentences')] },
            success: function(){
                const data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        Cookies.set('final', jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
    };

    render() {
        const {loading} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar/>
                <Block/>
                <Card>
                    <CardActions>
                    <Button size="large"
                            fullWidth={true}
                            onClick={this.handleClickLoading}>Submit</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
                <Fade
                    in={loading}
                    unmountOnExit
                    >
                <BottomBar/>
                </Fade>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

and its trying to get data ran through python scripts through a Flask server:

```
...
def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None,
                max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True,
                automatic_options=True):
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, list):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, list):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator


@app.route("/")

def home():
    return "hi"
@app.route("/index")


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def login():
   message = None
   if request.method == 'POST':
        datafromjs = request.form['mydata']
        result = "test"
        resp = make_response('{"response": '+result+'}')
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
        resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        return resp
        return render_template('login.html', message='')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And this is the console output onClick from the browser:
[image]

and Flask:

[image]

The javascript is trying to fetch the output of a few python functions given a few parameters.

I'm just at an impasse here and it's the last cog in my project. I have no prior experience with this kind of stuff but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not to use [Flask-Cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a CORS issue, like JJ Hakala points out. Even if you are going to the same domain (localhost) but on a different port (8080 -> 5000) then you need an authorisation header to be present (server side).

If you can ensure that the header `access-control-allow-origin:*` is present (a wildcard domain approach) in server responses, then you should have no more ajax issues.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing